# MySQL 5.6 Workbench and my.ini

Tags: mysql

I've recently installed MySQL 5.6 on a windows 7 PC.  It did have version 5.5.  When I open up Workbench and click on options file, it tells me that it is still looking at my.ini in my MySQL 5.5 folder.  How do I tell 5.6 that it's my.ini is in its own folder?

Comment: I would really recommend uninstalling the previous version.

Comment: I did that before I installed 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new server instance and point it to correct folder.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may have solved it. Not sure why it happened (unless some setting has remained in the registry after removing 5.5) but I can manage the server instances, and in the System Profile tab, looks like I can change where it looks for the options file.